# How to remove tcp header of packets captured with dumpcap?

Tags: wireshark, packet

The traffic from Wireshark saved into a file with dumpcap.
In this file a have for example :

```
€     X       `þ $À6
@ íëÃNxXÀ¨£ P&E»kKí¨<`PEà;  
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: private
```

And I want to see only :

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: private

      On windows 7 and I use this commands :
      cd\pro*
      cd wires*
      tshark -D
      dumpcap -i 5 -s 96-w packets.cap
```

Answer (score 1):

The "garbage" prefixing the data you are interested in are the protocol layers (ethernet, ip and transport headers)

When you save the data captured with dumpcap, you are also recording these protocol layers.

To filter them away to only view the TCP data, you need to process your data through a program. [Tcpflow](http://www.circlemud.org/jelson/software/tcpflow/tcpflow.1.html) is a tool that can extract data from tcp packets.

Take a look at [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/206734/how-do-i-make-tcpdump-not-print-the-tcp-headers) question, which is essentially the same you are asking.

In your scenario, you would want the command to be something like:

```
tcpflow -C -r <your-pcap-file>
```

Comment: I use this commands: cd\pro*
wires*
tshark -D
dumpcap -i 5 -w packets.cap but I am working on windows in command prompt .What command to use to working tcpflow

Comment: Perhaps "tshark -r infile -T fields -e data"? - http://ask.wireshark.org/questions/15374/dump-raw-packet-data-field-only

Comment: If I write this I see in command prompt the text in ASCII.If I write tshark -r infile -T fields -e data -w output.raw the file is like infile

Answer (score -1):

Are all lines the same as the one in your example?

Assuming this is on a *nix system, you could use grep or awk, or a combination of the two, eg:

```
cat dumpfile | grep HTTP
```

or

```
cat dumpfile | awk -F; '{print $1}'
```